# Ansible/Jinja2 how to append key into list of dict

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I would like to have dictionary defined in ansible like this

```
vhosts:
  git_branch_1:
    - { a: example.com, customer: a }
    - { a: example.com, customer: b }
    - { a: example.org, customer: a }
  git_branch_2:
    - { a: example.com, customer: x }
    - { a: example.org, customer: y }
```

Some tasks I need to loop only over dict keys, this works fine

```
- name: "just debug"
  debug: msg={{ item }}
  with_items: "{{ vhosts.keys() }}"
```

But some tasks I would like to iterate over list from each key, and append the key as another property of dict, so I would like to combine/create new dict from this original dict, that will look like this:

```
combined_vhosts:
  - { a: example.com, customer: a, branch: git_branch_1 }
  - { a: example.com, customer: b, branch: git_branch_1 }
  ...
  - { a: example.com, customer: x, branch: git_branch_2 }
```

And in some tasks I just need to get only the top level domain:

```
domains:
  - example.com
  - example.org
```

Is there a way, how can I achive this in ansible set_facts / jinja2 notation or do I have to write a custom plugin for ansible in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this with `set_fact`:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    vhosts:
      git_branch_1:
        - { a: example.com, customer: a }
        - { a: example.com, customer: b }
        - { a: example.org, customer: a }
      git_branch_2:
        - { a: example.com, customer: x }
        - { a: example.org, customer: y }
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        tmp_vhosts: "{{ item.value | map('combine',dict(branch=item.key)) | list }}"
      with_dict: "{{ vhosts }}"
      register: combined_vhosts
    - set_fact:
        combined_vhosts: "{{ combined_vhosts.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.tmp_vhosts') | sum(start=[]) }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ combined_vhosts }}"
```

More details about this trick with `set_fact` and `with_` in [this post](https://ansibledaily.com/process-complex-variables-with-set_fact-and-with_items/).

To fetch all domains, you can use `json_query('*[].a')`.

Comment: This is genious! Thanks. Постоянно натыкаюсь на твои ответы)