# How to convert a dict of key=dict pairs to a list of dicts extending each item with key in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have a dict of user definitions (`users_def`) and a list of user names to actually set up (`users`):

```
users_def:
  john:
    attr1: val1
    attr2: val2
  alice:
    attr1: val1
    attr2: val2

users:
  - alice
```

I would like to get a list of users with all their attributes from `users_def`, including the username:

```
[
  {
     "name": "alice",
     "attr1": "val1",
     "attr2": "val2"
  }
]
```

How can I achieve this in Ansible?

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202825/ansible-jinja2-how-to-append-key-into-list-of-dict) to a similar question but when I try:

```
- set_fact:
    _users: "{{ item.value | map('combine', {'name': item.key}) | list }}"
  loop: "{{ users_def | dict2items }}"
```

I get this error:

```
failed to combine variables, expected dicts but got a 'str' and a 'dict': \n\"attr1\"\n{\"name\": \"john\"}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below does the job

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _users: "{{ _users|default([]) +
                    [{'name': item.0}|combine(item.1)] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ users }}"
        - "{{ users|map('extract', users_def)|list }}"
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. For completeness, I've settled on a version using `loop: "{{ users|zip(users|map('extract', users_def)|list)|list }}"` instead of `with_together`.